# How can I sort generic list DESC and ASC?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

How can I sort generic list DESC and ASC? With LINQ and without LINQ? I'm using VS2008.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> li = new List<int>();

        li.Add(456);
        li.Add(123);
        li.Add(12345667);
        li.Add(0);
        li.Add(1);

        li.Sort();

        foreach (int item in li)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.ToString() + "\n");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 334, accepted):

With Linq

```
var ascendingOrder = li.OrderBy(i => i);
var descendingOrder = li.OrderByDescending(i => i);
```

Without Linq

```
li.Sort((a, b) => a.CompareTo(b)); // ascending sort
li.Sort((a, b) => b.CompareTo(a)); // descending sort
```

Note that without Linq, the list itself is being sorted. With Linq, you're getting an ordered enumerable of the list but the list itself hasn't changed. If you want to mutate the list, you would change the Linq methods to something like

```
li = li.OrderBy(i => i).ToList();
```

Comment: @onedaywhen If you feel that another user's answer is incorrect you should be commenting, voting, and/or providing an answer you feel is correct, not editing another person's answer to be what you think is correct.

Comment: I think that for descending order it is much clearer to use `li.Sort((a, b) => b.CompareTo(a));` than the `-1*` approach used here. I edited the answer accordingly but @Servy reverted it.

Comment: @Servy: I think the answer is materially correct but in one case has used some slightly odd logic. The [faq for editing](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) says, "Some common reasons to edit [include]... to correct minor mistakes." So it appears that "editing another person's answer to be what you think is correct" is encouraged (not proscribed, as you suggest).

Comment: @onedaywhen When the author made a mistake in writing out what they intended, changing it to be what they intended to write is fine.  Changing code form what someone else thought the solution should be to using a different approach that you feel should be used instead is not an appropriate edit.

Comment: @Servy: do you have a citation for your assertion (faq, meta, etc)? As I said before, I think my edit is legit as per the faq.

Comment: @onedaywhen Sure; you'll see it anywhere you see editing described.  From the help center, "When should I edit posts?  [...] To clarify the meaning of the post (without changing that meaning)"

Comment: Or just `-a.CompareTo(b)`.

Comment: Good approach to sort the string type list 
li.OrderBy(i => i);

Answer (score 96):

Without Linq:

Ascending:

```
li.Sort();
```

Descending:

```
li.Sort();
li.Reverse();
```

Comment: `Sort()` is a void method, so you can't chain the `Reverse()` to it in this manner. You'll need 2 separate operations. However, with LINQ you could chain it to an `OrderBy` but at that point you should just use `OrderByDescending` instead.

Answer (score 21):

without linq,
use `Sort()` and then `Reverse()` it.

Answer (score 10):

I was checking all the answer above and wanted to add one more additional information.
I wanted to sort the list in DESC order and I was searching for the solution which is faster for bigger inputs and I was using this method earlier :-

```
li.Sort();
li.Reverse();
```

but my test cases were failing for exceeding time limits, so below solution worked for me:-

```
li.Sort((a, b) => b.CompareTo(a));
```

So Ultimately the conclusion is that 2nd way of Sorting list in Descending order is bit faster than the previous one.

Answer (score -3):

Very simple way to sort List with int values in Descending order:

```
li.Sort((a,b)=> b-a);
```

Hope that this helps!

Comment: This isn't what `int.CompareTo(int)` does door a reason. See [the source at referencesource.microsoft.com](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/int32.cs,225942ed7b7a3252) which says: "*Need to use compare because subtraction will wrap to positive for very large neg numbers, etc.*". If you have `b = int.MinValue` and `a = 1` (say), this will fail. Sometimes a method call is worth it.

Comment: Question says about generic lists sorting. "-" operation wouldn't even compile for many types. And for compiled set of types you can have numeric overflow error as mentioned in comment before