# Lambda Sort asc

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I'm new to lambda expressions and I'm having some trouble figuring out how to sort in Ascending order.

The code I currently have is only sorting my X values alphabetically. I want to sort my Y values Ascendingly.

I know I need to use `Count()` somewhere but I don't know where.

below is my code:

```
var query = PIList
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Failcode)
    .ThenByDescending(x => x.Failcode)
    .Select(x => x.Failcode)
    .Distinct();

foreach (var value in query)
{
    PIFailCodeChart.Series[0].Points
        .AddXY(value, PIList.Where(x => x.Failcode == value).Count());
}
```

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks, @Eddie_cat. You beat me to the chase though. haha

Comment: You're sorting by `Failcode` both times... how is that useful? And in what way is a `Failcode` an X value or a Y value? You need to give more information about your data here... (And if you're just adding values to a graph, why does the order matter?)

Comment: Pretty sure OrderBy does ascending by default.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i sort DESC and ASC in list generic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062513/how-can-i-sort-desc-and-asc-in-list-generic)

Comment: This is a duplicate but I don't think it deserves downvotes.

Comment: what happens when someone gets downvotes? I've only been using stackExchange for like a month.

Comment: Your reputation goes down, but only by a couple points.  In the future, see if you can put some more effort into finding your answer when you are writing your question :)

Comment: As a new user, nothing happens.  Its the community telling you that you need to work on your quesiton because its either not clear, or not well researched.  Take no offense.. just do like @Pheonix says and improve your question next time.

Comment: @Joe Suggest reading [this useful article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks, I'll read the article before posting any new questions.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a .NET Fiddle showing how](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HJV65o) and here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<string> s = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c", "a"};
        var asc = s.OrderBy(e => e).ToList<string>();
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", asc));
    }
}
```

This outputs `a, a, b, c`, an ascending sorted list.

You can do this:

```
var query = PIList.Distinct(x => x.FailCode)
    .OrderBy(x => x.FailCode)
    .Select(x => x.FailCode);
```

Comment: Note the `OrderBy` instead of `OrderByDescending`

Comment: That did confuse me when I was first learning LINQ.  It's a bit inconsistent. :)