# How to generate five sets of random numbers

Tags: c#, random

I am trying to generate five sets of a random number in c# order by highest number and comma-separated

I tried using

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] randNumber = new int[5];
    Random rand = new Random();
    Console.Write("The random numbers are: "); 
    for (int h = 0; h < randNumber.Length; h++)
    {
        randNumber[h] = rand.Next(1, 20);           
    } 
    Console.Write(string.Join(", ", randNumber));        
}
```

I am getting output only of one set without sorting(Highest to lowest) i.e.

> The random numbers are: 12, 2, 12, 19, 11

The Expected Output should be like this::

1. 11,9,7,6,4
2. 13,8,7,6,4
3. 13,9,7,6,2
4. 17.9,7,6,1
5. 1,6,7,4,14

Comment: Once you have your numbers, you should order it yourself (e.g. `Array.Sort(...)`)

Comment: See how you did a `for` loop? Do **another** one that wraps around your existing code. If it runs 5 times, you should be good to go. Also ensure that `int[] randNumber = new int[5];
            Random rand = new Random();` is **before** both loops. Also use `Sort` like @dcg suggested.

Comment: you need another loop to execute that code 5 times, cause you are generating only 5 numbers right now

Comment: Related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062513/how-can-i-sort-generic-list-desc-and-asc

Comment: why is the 5-th set not sorted? is that on purpose?

Comment: Also Remember Random class is a pseudo random number generator, it starts repeating after sometime due to poor seed value, for genuine random number use Cryptography APIs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another one...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Random R = new Random();
    List<List<int>> sets = new List<List<int>>();
    for(int s=1; s<=5; s++)
    {
        List<int> set = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            set.Add(R.Next(1, 20));
        }
        set.Sort();
        set.Reverse();
        sets.Add(set);
    }

    for(int i=1; i<=sets.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i.ToString() + ". " + string.Join(", ", sets[i-1]));
    }

    Console.Write("Press Enter to quit");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Example output:

```
1. 19, 18, 12, 9, 3
2. 18, 17, 15, 5, 3
3. 18, 11, 9, 7, 1
4. 13, 12, 10, 10, 6
5. 12, 6, 5, 5, 3
Press Enter to quit
```

Comment: Its working as Expected,Thank You so much "Idle_Mind", You really saved my day,God Bless You

Comment: @TauheedAlam do you understand why this code gives you the desired result and why yours did not?

Answer (score 3):

Just enhanced your code.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] randNumber = new int[5];
            Random rand = new Random();
            Console.WriteLine("The random numbers are: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                for (int h = 0; h < randNumber.Length; h++)
                {
                    randNumber[h] = rand.Next(1, 20);
                }
                randNumber = randNumber.OrderByDescending(x => x).ToArray();
                Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", randNumber));
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it:

```
var rnd = new Random();

Console.WriteLine(
    string.Join("\n",
        Enumerable
            .Range(1, 5) // returns an IEnumerable<int> containing 1,2,3,4,5.
            .Select(s =>   // for each int in the IEnumerable
                string.Join(",",
                Enumerable
                    .Range(1, 5)
                    .Select(i => rnd.Next(1, 20)) // get a random number.
                    .OrderByDescending(r => r) // order the inner IEnumerable
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Result (well, one possible result, anyway):

```
17,17,10,2,1
19,10,10,8,2
17,16,9,3,3
17,16,8,5,1
18,14,13,10,3
```

Comment: "trying to generate five sets " wouldn't you need one more call of this nice `Range...Select...` Kung Fu ?

Comment: Maybe you should add some explanations for the linq stuff as it seems that OP might not be a C# pro yet (no offence).

Comment: @MongZhu No, the second number is the count, not the max so it will enumerate 5 numbers, starting from 1. See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.range?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: @Joelius we should rather read the post and not the docs ;) OP wants to have 5 * 5 = 25 numbers

Comment: @MongZhu Ohh that's what you meant. Yea in that case it would require an outer loop of 5. Just using 25 instead of 5 wouldn't work because of the requested output format.

Comment: @Joelius there is no loop necessary. Pure linq. Just one more call (as I said in my comment) But I guess Zohar knows what I am talking about.

Comment: @MongZhu Maybe my wording wasn't correct. I don't say you _need_ a loop. But the current code has to be repeated five times, it doesn't matter whether you use a loop or `Enumerable.Range` again. We should stop this discussion now ;)

Comment: @MongZhu I've added another `Range...Select` to repeat five times.